# How to make the navigation bar / tab bar opaque?

Tags: ios, swift

When I do the up and down in collectionView, the color of my tabbar changes, and the navigation bar changes in the ball area where I have it. how do I fix this?

[image]

I did this, but it didn't work.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black // istediğiniz renk
        tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black // istediğiniz renk
    } else {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black // orijinal renk
        tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black // orijinal renk
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tab & Navigation Bar changes after upgrading to XCode 13 (& iOS 15)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281380/tab-navigation-bar-changes-after-upgrading-to-xcode-13-ios-15)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your tab bar is translucent. You can change this by setting the `isTranslucent` property to false. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623458-istranslucent

Making the navigation bar translucent is a little more tricky, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25846056/95309